# WPF Localization with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, localization

I want to learn how to localize a WPF project written in C#.
I found the following webpage and followed Example of WPF Localization, Run Dialog Box Example
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx
I created a new project according to the description and everything worked until I have to use the LocBaml utility.
I tried to download that utility from MS but the URL http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=160016 does not work (anymore).
Then I searched the internet for that tool and I found something but it seems this is some old version. I was able to use the command LocBaml /parse RunDialog.resources.dll /out: to generate a "RunDialog.resources.dll.CSV" and the CSV file was created but the file is empty.

Now my questions:

1. Does anybody else have experience with localization and the LocBaml utility and knows where to find an updated version of that utility and maybe some more detailed description or sample how to use it?
2. Is localization using the description in the MS article above the best way to work with localization or are there better alternatives?

Currently I work just with an example to learn it. The program which I plan to localize is in planning and I will design it from scratch so I am flexible to use whatever is a good way to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach. It's very easy.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies

Nice tool for managing resources:
https://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/